# How do I decode my md5 encryption and how do I call the function properly?

Tags: java, android, encryption, md5

I have two questions 1 I have the following code and I don't know how to use it from another part of my code, i.e when the user registers to encrypt my string password

```
public static final String md5(final String toEncrypt) { 
    try { 
        final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");               
        digest.update(toEncrypt.getBytes()); 
        final byte[] bytes = digest.digest();       

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) { 
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", bytes[i])); 
        } 

        return sb.toString().toLowerCase();
    } 
    catch (Exception exc) { return ""; // Impossibru! }
}
```

Second question is how would I decrypt that string when I pull it from my database to match what a user types in a editbox.

Comment: MD5 is **not** encryption.

Comment: MD5 is a meat grinder. Cow goes in, hamburger comes out. You can NOT take that hamburger and glue it back together into a cow. You don't decode an md5 hash, because it can NOT be decoded. you take the user's password, hash that with md5, then compare the two md5 hashes.

Comment: ok then how do I call this function so that I can ecrypt what the user types in the box and match it to the database?

Comment: sorry im in the process of learning java and not 100% sure on things yet

Comment: @MarcB that's the best description of hashing I've heard.  I'm definitely going to use that at work when people don't get it.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @user2030485 Start by using the right term. It's called _hashing_, not _encrypting_. Encrypting lets you get the original data back out; hashing just guarantees that if you put in the same input, you get the same output, and if you put in a different input, you get a different output -- it doesn't guarantee that you can get the input from the output.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes cryptographic hashes are not reversible by design, that is the point. The "doesn't guarantee" is really weak and provides the wrong impression.

Answer (score 8):

1. You're not supposed to "decrypt" MD5. The whole point of a hashing function is to make it very hard to unhash it. <sub>(of course, hackers try and sometimes succeed, but that's a different topic.)</sub> You hash the user's input, and *then* compare it with the hashed password in the database.
2. To call it, simply use `String hashedPassword = md5("some person's password");`. Just like a normal method.
3. You should probably actually do some exception handling, rather than just ignoring them. At *least* log them, at the very minimum. Or return `null`, or use a `throws` clause. Just don't completely ignore them.
4. I don't even know what's going on on line 3... you should probably make those separate lines. Also, your indentation is <s>a bit</s> extremely strange. You will spend **much** more time reading your code than writing it, so make it readable now, and you'll thank your past self later. In fact, I already see a bug:

   ```
   catch (Exception exc) { return ""; // Impossibru! }
   ```

   The close bracket is commented out.

Answer (score 1):

md5 is a one way encryption method. The only way to find what the encrypted version is, is to md5 hash combinations of characters until the results match

Comment: Which is why MD5, in fact any hash function even with salting, should not be used for securing passwords.